# How to make the text size in app inventor 2 device independent

Tags: android, app-inventor

My app contains list,button,labels. The text elements in them are looking small on Big devices and big in small devices.How to make the text size device independent in app inventor2.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure APP Inventor whether can get the info of the device,but alternately,You can make a "Setting" page in your app,let the user to select the text size and save the selected value in the TinyDB.

After that,during every page initialization,change the text size according to the selected value,please click the URL below to see the APP Inventor 2 example screenshot:

[App Inventor 2 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fr41.png)